# how to count the some fixed values in each row of a matrix and the different columns of all possible pairs of two rows of a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix and I want to count the some fixed values (i) in each row and (ii) each column of two rows of a matrix by using the loop command.  kindly check the attached files and explanations are given in these files. . thank you so much in advance.

for example, `A=matrix(c(0,1,2,1,1,0,2,0,1),3,3)`. `n`=3 number of columns. `N`=3 number of rows.
`ro`= how many times 1 occur in each row.

for example in first row 1 occur once time, in second row 1 occur two times and in third row 1 occur again once time. so, `sum(ro)` = `4`.
`r1`= `n-ro`.   total remaining values in each row. for example in first row r1= 2 because two values 0 and 2 are remaining values. in second row the remaining values is only 0 so `r1` = `1` for second row.

now I want to count the some fixed values in each columns of two rows. `r11` = `(1,1)` it means that i want to check the this fixed value is occurred between the columns of two rows or not. also, `roo` = `(0,0)` and `(2,2)`, `ro2` = `(0,2),(2,0)`. `ro1` = `(1,0),(0,1),(1,2), (2,1)`.
then at the end i want to calculate this expression. Thank you so much in advance.
B(k)= sum(a start from 1 to N)(ro^4-ro^3-ror1)-sum(a not equal to b)roo*ro2(ro2(72ro2-99)-roo(81ro2-45)+68)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a matrix. i want to count the frequency of R1 how many times  1 occur in each row. Ro how many times 0 and 2 occur in each row. R11=(1,1) how many times this fix value occur in each column of two rows. R01=(0,1),(1,0), (1,2) and (2,1) occur in each column of two different rows etc.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrixx

```
ro <- rowSums(A == 1)
ro
[1] 1 2 1
```

Then do the subtraction from the number of columns of the matrix

```
ncol(A) - ro
[1] 2 1 2
```

---

The last part of the question is not clear.  May be this helps

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(A), sep=""))
str_count(v1, "01")
#[1] 1 0 1
str_count(v1, "12")
#[1] 1 0 0
```

Comment: I have a matrix. i want to count the frequency of R1 how many times  1 occur in each row. Ro how many times 0 and 2 occur in each row. R11=(1,1) how many times this fix value occur in each column of two rows. R01=(0,1),(1,0), (1,2) and (2,1) occur in each column of two different rows etc.

Comment: @UmerDaraz If you need to do this for every row, do `apply(A, 1, table)`

Comment: can you share your email address with me? I want to send you picture then maybe you will understand it and help me.